# Automount is not mounting NFS shared home folder on centos 7 when using LDAP login

Tags: ldap, fedora, centos7, systemd, automount

```
These are the error messages that I can see in /var/log/messages folder:

     failed to bind to LDAP server ldap://x.x.x.x: Can't contact LDAP server
    bind_ldap_simple: lookup(ldap): Unable to bind to the LDAP server: (default), error Can't contact LDAP server
     failed to bind to LDAP server ldap://X.X.X.X: Can't contact LDAP server
     failed to bind to LDAP server ldap://X.X.X.X: Can't contact LDAP server
```

Comment: These are the error messages that i can see in /var/log/messages folder.
 <passwd=-1> failed to bind to LDAP server ldap://x.x.x.x: Can't contact LDAP server
bind_ldap_simple: lookup(ldap): Unable to bind to the LDAP server: (default), error Can't contact LDAP server
<group/member="gdm"> failed to bind to LDAP server ldap://X.X.X.X: Can't contact LDAP server
<group/member="gdm"> failed to bind to LDAP server ldap://X.X.X.X: Can't contact LDAP server

Answer (score 0):

```
I had to enable NetworkManager-wait-online service by executing the command below

    systemctl enable NetworkManager-wait-online.service

Then I had to change timeout in 
/usr/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager-wait-online.service file. 
I set the timeout to 60 seconds and it worked for me.
I am listing the modified file with changed timeout below.

    [Unit]
    Description=Network Manager Wait Online
    Requisite=NetworkManager.service
    After=NetworkManager.service
    Wants=network.target
    Before=network.target network-online.target

    [Service]
    Type=oneshot
    ExecStart=/usr/bin/nm-online -s -q --timeout=60

    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target
```